# HTTP URL sniffer using python

Tags: python, windows, sockets, network-programming, python-sockets

I'm working on the tracking the browsing urls, only outgoing packets in all OS (windows, linux, Mac)

I can read the TCP packet using python sockets but unable to find the URL domain names.

please guide or suggest me to achieve this.

Comment: Investiage [`scapy`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

Comment: thanks a lot, its working, how can i get the process id of browser's tabs?